# Create SplashScreen with layout Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im trying to create a splashscreen in Xamarin Studio.

I did the following:

- Created my layout with the splashimage.
- Created a theme (styles.xml) so the titlebar was hidden.
- Created a activity which sets the contentview and then lets the thread sleep.

For some reason it did not work and I hoped you could help me out here:

SplashScreen.cs (SplashScreen activity)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace EvoApp
{
    [Activity (MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash")]           
    public class SplashScreen : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            this.SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Splash);

            ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.evolticLogo);
            image.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.Splash);

            Thread.Sleep (2000);
            StartActivity (typeof(MainActivity));
        }
    }
}
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

So the result of this is a blank SplashActivity....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screen is blank because by calling `Thread.Sleep` then `StartActivity` in `OnCreateView`, you are first pausing the UI thread (which will cause nothing to display) and are then exiting the activity immediately by using `StartActivity`.

To fix this, shift `Thread.Sleep()` and `StartActivity()` into a background thread:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    this.SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Splash);

    ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.evolticLogo);
    image.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.Splash);

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run( () => {
        Thread.Sleep (2000);
        StartActivity (typeof(MainActivity));
    });
}
```

Comment: This actually works! however there is a blank screen of 1 second happening before the splash screen is rendered. Any idea how to avoid that blank screen?

Comment: My solution for this 1 second blank screen was adding a style to the activity (which gets applied before 'setContentView') with the same background color as my splash view. That makes the entry to the splash layout better