# animated splashscreen with loading progressbar in android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

i am creating a splashscreen with progressbar in xamarin monoandroid in visual Studio 2015
I have seen so many post regarding splash screen only with logo but i need animated splashscreen with animated loading progress bar in that.

SplashScreen.cs

```
namespace Splash_Screen
{
      [Activity(Label = "Splash Screen App", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class SplashScreen : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            //Display Splash Screen for 4 Sec  
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashLayout);
               TextView loadingText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.progress_bar);
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            //Start Activity1 Activity  
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        }
    }
}
```

SplashLayout.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="loading"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100" />
</LinearLayout>
```

splash_screen_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

  <gradient
      android:angle="90"
      android:centerColor="#FF223333"
      android:endColor="@android:color/black"
      android:startColor="@android:color/black" />

</shape>
```

i am getting a blank black screen instead of splash screen.What should be done here

i need like this as in this image with no actionbar

[image]

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(4000);` will lock the UI thread which is why you're seeing a black screen. Put it into a background operation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770296/create-splashscreen-with-layout-xamari/27770817#27770817

Comment: @matthewrdev able adding mentioned code,i am able to see splash xml layout but when i open my app it shows blank black screen first,followed by splash layout then to main activity.another issue in this is progressbar has become static its not progressing itself

Comment: @dafodil have you ever found a good solution for this? I am looking into similar implementation